# Get small element index till array length

Tags: javascript

I have to sort an array and want to get index so that I can sort another array on the basis of this index..
There are two array `a` and `b` I saved division of that array in third array that is `sortDiv` now I want index of small element so that I can sort `a` and `b` according to index..
Code is like

```js
   var a = [6, 7, 8, 9];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var sortA = [],
  sortB = [],
  sortDiv = [];
var div = a[0] / b[0];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  sortDiv.push(a[i] / b[i]);
}
var temp = sortDiv;
for (var i = 1; i < sortDiv.length; i++) {
  var val = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
  var key = sortDiv.indexOf(val);
  sortA.push(a[key]);
  sortB.push(b[key]);

  if (key > -1)
temp.splice(key, 1);
}
console.log(sortA + " " + sortB);
```

I got `[9,8]` for a and `[4,3]` for b..while I want `a=[9,8,7,6] b=[1,2,3,4]`
But splice is not a good option..I need a function that remove only element not an index..any idea please?

**UPDATED**
As problem is solved but I want to know that
Is it possible to remove element but not an index in array?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you want .

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla Yes, I would comment the same thing. Also remove all the unnecessary code to be more specific.

Comment: @HeemanshuBhalla I have updated my question please check it out

Comment: check out this stackoverflow link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387571/javascript-array-splice-without-changing-the-index

Comment: That helped thanx @RajeshJangid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not removing element just replacing it with maximum element +1 and it will work fine here is the updated code

```
var a = [6, 7, 8, 9];
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var sortA = [],
  sortB = [],
  sortDiv = [];
var div = a[0] / b[0];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  sortDiv.push(a[i] / b[i]);
}
console.log(sortDiv);

var temp = sortDiv;
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, temp);  // here we find the maximum
max += 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= sortDiv.length; i++) {
  var val = Math.min.apply(Math, temp);
  console.log(val);
  var key = sortDiv.indexOf(val);
  sortA.push(a[key]);
  sortB.push(b[key]);
  temp[key] = max;   // here we update the minimum with maximum+1
}
console.log(sortA + " " + sortB);
```

Comment: Isn't it possible with splice? can we remove element from array not an index ?

Comment: using splice changes indexes of elements after one iteration hence we cannot use splice here

Comment: don't know exactly but i think it is not possible to remove element with keeping the index undefined

Answer (score 0):

If the question is about using splice to remove an item based on the value and not the index, get the index, then use splice:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
a.splice(a.indexOf('b'), 1);
console.log(a); // ["a", "c"]
```

Comment: I have used splice but it doesnot give an appropriate result

Comment: 'appropriate' or 'correct'? Are you trying to remove your use of slice, correct your use of splice, or something else?

Comment: yeah I meant correct..I didnot get my answer as I want..I do not know splice is correct method to use or not