# How do I remove an item from an array by value but keep the original index order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

How do I remove an item from an array by its value, but still keep the index order instead of the array re-indexing the items?
To be clearer, the following code will remove the item by value, but it will re-index the values too meaning that 15 will have an index of 0 instead of 1 after we splice 5 out.

```
var arr = [5, 15, 110, 210, 550];
var index = arr.indexOf(5);

if (index > -1) {
   arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Then you want to clear the value not to remove it...

Comment: so what value do you want to put in its place?

Comment: `arr[index] = undefined`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387571/javascript-array-splice-without-changing-the-index

Comment: delete arr[index];

Comment: @ManManam: That will prevent functions from iterating over the entry, effectively changing the index of following items.

Comment: @Cerbrus - it will prevent *built-ins* from iterating over that value, using `delete` will not change the length or indices, other that the deleted item being set to "empty" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the index instead of slicing set the index value to undefined...

```js
var arr = [5, 15, 110, 210, 550];
var index = arr.indexOf(5);

if (index > -1) {
   arr[index] = undefined;
}
console.log(arr);

arr.forEach(function(item){
  if(item !== undefined){
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

you can always iterate, with the conditional  filtering the undefined values..

Comment: The downside of that is then you have to check if item is undefined every time you loop. If you do delete arr[index]; then forEach and for-in will skip over that index for you.